# What is a word that describes a perfectionist that only judges their own work?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

That person doesn't need to do everything perfect but only specifically focused on the things they're talented in. Also that person doesn't care what others think of their standard or judge another persons standard.

Comment: 'perfectionist' sounds right to me already. What is wrong with that word for the situation you're describing? Can you clarify?

Comment: You've basically described a perfectionist. "Demanding" is what I'd call someone who judges others' work.

Comment: A perfectionist is a propensity for being displeased with ANYTHING that is not perfect or does not meet extremely high standards. That sounds like a selfish person and that's true. I want to know a word that explains one that obviously is not selfish.

Comment: JFA ANYTHING meaning a perfectionist has to do EVERYTHING perfect and will even argue with other people about how that other persons work isn't good enough. That's not necessarily demanding but suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary.com site gives [self-perfection](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-perfection?s=ts) as the noun denoting the concept, and Google returns approximately 5000 hits on self-perfectionist...so, if you're not above a bit of a neologism, self-perfectionist fits, and is not without precedent.

If you are a self-perfectionist, you can always leave room for later improvement of the term, when and if you discover a better one.

Notably, Dictionary.com gives two "Historical Examples" of 'self-perfection' use, one from a translation of Plutarch, another from an English-language survey of Russian literature.